# gpg: public key decryption failed: No such file or directory

Tags: encryption, ssh, cryptography, aws-glue, gnupg

We are running commands in SSH in AWS Glue to decrypt file in EC2, all public key and private keys are imported and passing passphrase in --batch command, but errors out as:

***gpg: public key decryption failed: No such file or directory
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
failed to run commands: exit status 2***

```
import boto3
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')

script = [
    "sudo su -",
    "export GPG_TTY=$(tty)",
    "gpg --batch --passphrase 1234 -o /data/decrypted/file.TXT -d /data/encrypted/file.TXT.pgp",
]

response = ssm_client.send_command(
    InstanceIds=[instance_id],
    DocumentName=document_name,
    Parameters={'commands': script},
)
```